# Detect content changes on frame with javascript

Tags: javascript, frame

How to know if the content from a frame is changed with javascript? I have a html with 4 frames and I need to know if the content is changing after doing onclick in an input button.

Thanks

Comment: If the frame contents are from another site, you are likely not able to.for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches you can take:

- Change the click event handler so it also notifies the parent frame
- On an interval, get the content document of the frame and grab a copy of the body element's `innerHTML`. Then compare it to the previous version you got. (Then store it so you can compare it for the next poll)

Comment: Is there a sample how can I do for example the first one you can show me?